# php date time seems does not work properly

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I'm now inserting a `date/time` data into my `date/time field` in the database. I have tried many techniques such as:

```
 $date = date("d M Y");
 $date = date("d M Y", mktime());
 $date = getdate();
 $date = date("d M Y", strtotime('now'));
```

and also this function: `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Bangkok');`

but it still does not get the datetime.

This is my sql statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".TABLE_CONTENT."(`title`, `detail`, `crdate`, `modate`, `crby`, moby, isdel) VALUES('".$title."', '".$detail."', '".$crdate."', '".$modate."', '".$crby."', '".$moby."', $isdel)";
```

After performing the query I got only the `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in my database.

Any help or suggestion would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: i would suggest using varchar instead of date as your sql structure. and see if it is properly inserted

Comment: *"my date/time field"* - All of your *techniques* are missing a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your database fields are set to timestamp, so you'll have to insert data into the database fields in exactly that format.

So this would work

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You could also use the MySQL `NOW()`, which would insert the current timestamp into that field, although the timezone would be set to whatever timezone your server is on.

example:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO <table> (title, crdate) VALUES ('test', NOW())";
```